# fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'

Tags: git, github, homebrew, git-clone, macos-high-sierra

I tried to install brew on my mac (High Sierra) I always have this error:

> fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'

I tried to clone [brew](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew.git) manually but it's the same.

Do you have any idea how to fix my problem?

Answer (score 8):

This happens when `git` doesn't find the `git-remote-https` executable in the executables directory (`git --exec-path`), which in turns happen when compiling git on a machine which doesn't have all the dependencies available. Most likely one of libcurl-gnutls or libgnutls is missing on your system.